# Use integration by substitution to find the indefinite integral

Tags: integration

I thought I had indefinite integrals down but I'm a bit lost with this one.

Use integration by substitution to find the indefinite integral:

$$\int (x+4)\bigg(\frac{1}{3}x+8\bigg)^6 dx.$$

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not type the contents in the image?

Comment: In such integral with two linear factors, always it is better to substitute the one with higher power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\frac{x}{3}+8$. Then $3u=x+24$. Thus $x+4=3u-20$ and $dx=3du$. Hence,
$$\begin{align}\int(x+4)\bigg(\frac{x}{3}+8\bigg)^6dx&=\int(3u-20)u^6 (3du)\\
&=3\int(3u^7-20u^6)du\\
&=3\bigg[\frac{3u^8}{8}-\frac{20u^7}{7}\bigg]+C\\
&=
\end{align}$$
and proceed with back substitution.

Comment: Thank you very much, this explains it perfectly.

Comment: @user23432432 Welcome. You can upvote if you want.--)

Comment: I did but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.". When I get enough reputation I think it will update. Thanks again though.